# Power Automate Flow - Microsoft Authentification in receiving http request

Tags: http, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I have a power automate flow which starts when a http request is received.
To continue on, I need to have the microsoft user of the person who is calling the link. Is it possible to make a redirect to login.microsoftonline.com or something else? How can I read the users email?

[image]

UPDATE: I tried to handle this with a custom connection to the microsoft graph api. I set "enable onbehalf of login" to "true".
But now I get the following error:

> Connect cannot be used to activate this flow, either because this is not a valid connection or because it is not a connection you have access permission for. Either replace the connection with a valid connection you can access or have the connection owner activate the flow, so the connection is shared with you in the context of this flow.

Comment: What type of application or where is the flow being consumed/invoked from?  When you think about it, how do you propose to do what you want unless the user details are sent through in the payload OR you have some user interaction?

Comment: @Skin Thanks for your reply. I have a web-ticketing-system, where I can insert only hyperlinks. So the idea was, when a user clicks on that hyperlink, that I do some actions with a flow. But first of all I need to identify the user who clicked on that link. With the email-address I can identify the ticket-system-user and more. I already tried custom connectors, but this is not "dynamic".

Comment: Yeah, I don’t believe that’s possible. You’d need to either spin up a proper API that can have auth baked into it or use another mechanism like send an email which will then give you a FROM user you can then reference from within your flow.

Comment: @Skin hmmm you could be right. I think I would need a web controller who can authorize and then call the flow. I also checked out Azure Api Management. But no success